Downloading REST data which contains date_time attributes
I am attempting to download data from ArcGIS REST services in ArcGIS Pro using custom geometry. After some help, I've managed to get this to work and save the data as a shapefile. The data I'm downloading contains a "date_time" field, and only the "date" portion is being returned. After doing some reading, I've learned that shapefiles cannot store date_time. I tried saving to a gdb, but it was more complicated than I expected, and I'm a beginner.
Is there a simple way to save this to a gdb and retain "date_time"?
Or modify the query to calculate a "date" and "time" column separately?
Or return "date_time" as a string that I can then convert to "date" and "time" manually?
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer
from arcgis.geometry.filters import intersects

gis = GIS("pro")

#The ESRI JSON used to subset the REST data
geometry = {
  "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326},
  "rings": [
    [
      ["-124.785944", "49.142568"],
      ["-125.439631", "50.001049"],
      ["-124.928766", "50.335311"],
      ["-123.735655", "49.654732"],
      ["-124.404157", "49.265739"],
      ["-124.785944", "49.142568"]
    ]
  ]
}

# The REST service URL
rest_service_url = "https://gisp.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/FGP/MSDI_Dynamic_Current_Layer/MapServer/0"

# Access the feature layer using the REST service URL
layer = FeatureLayer(rest_service_url)

# Query the feature layer
features = layer.query(where="1=1", geometry_filter=intersects(geometry, 4326))

print(f"Number of features found: {len(features.features)}")

# Save to local Dir
output_dir = r"C:\Users\name\Documents\"  

# Save features to shp
features.save(output_dir, "currents.shp")

Thanks!

what do the returned dates look like.  I think they should look ilke 1717066800000

It's a date field with "2024-05-28" for example.

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/feature-layer-to-geodataframe-datetime-field/m-p/1241043/highlight/true#M8163

@dubbbdan thanks for passing this along, but it looks like the inverse of my situation. The solution you linked converts UNIX timestamps to date_time objects, but my data is being returned as date_time and only the "date" is being stored in the shapefile

yes, I suspect somewhere in features.save it converts to a date.  The provided link would allow you to convert to an ISO Time string before you feature.save to a shapefile.

The data hosted on the provided REST service, serve the datetime field as a unix time string.

https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-questions/time-disappears-when-exporting-from-query/m-p/174706/highlight/true#M9866

I don't have ArcGis, but I will attempt to explain.
The data on the provided REST service serve data that look like

Before you feature.save to a shapefile, you need to manually edit features to have a string representation of the time before you write to a shapefile.
You can achieve this using datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp.  Something like:
date_time = 1717642800000
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(date_time * 1e-3).isoformat())
# '2024-06-06T03:00:00'

If the data are not in UTC, you will have to handle the time zone your self.
I cant test on my end, but I think this should work:

from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer
from arcgis.geometry.filters import intersects
from datetime import datetime #new

def convert_timestamps(feature_set, field_names, use_iso=True):
    """Converts timestamps (UNIX epoch in [ms]) into datetime objects by modifying the feature set directly."""
    for feature in feature_set.features:
        for attribute_name in feature.attributes:
            if attribute_name in field_names:
                if use_iso:
                    feature.attributes[attribute_name] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(feature.attributes[attribute_name] * 1e-3).isoformat()
                else:
                    feature.attributes[attribute_name] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(feature.attributes[attribute_name] * 1e-3)

gis = GIS("pro")

#The ESRI JSON used to subset the REST data
geometry = {
  "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326},
  "rings": [
    [
      ["-124.785944", "49.142568"],
      ["-125.439631", "50.001049"],
      ["-124.928766", "50.335311"],
      ["-123.735655", "49.654732"],
      ["-124.404157", "49.265739"],
      ["-124.785944", "49.142568"]
    ]
  ]
}

# The REST service URL
rest_service_url = "https://gisp.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/FGP/MSDI_Dynamic_Current_Layer/MapServer/0"

# Access the feature layer using the REST service URL
layer = FeatureLayer(rest_service_url)

# The REST service URL
rest_service_url = "https://gisp.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/FGP/MSDI_Dynamic_Current_Layer/MapServer/0"

# Access the feature layer using the REST service URL
layer = FeatureLayer(rest_service_url)

# Query the feature layer
features = layer.query(where="1=1", geometry_filter=intersects(geometry, 4326)).sdf #new

convert_timestamps(features, ['date_time'], use_iso=True) # new

features = features.to_featurelayer() # new

print(f"Number of features found: {len(features.features)}")

# Save to local Dir
output_dir = r"C:\Users\name\Documents\"  

# Save features to shp
features.save(output_dir, "currents.shp")

